# Spring-boot with two EntityManager and abstract dao layer

Tags: java, database, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Spring-boot project, in my project I defined two EntityManager - for two different DB.

All of my entities (tables) are common for the two different DB.

The only thing that is different is the Dao layer - but because some of my db queries are shared I decided to create - a common Dao abstract layer. and i added a getEntityManager()  function to the class that extend the abstract class.

Example:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(value = "secondaryTransactionManager")
@javax.transaction.Transactional
public class TasksSecondaryDao extends TasksDaoAbstract {

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "secondary")
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 @Override
 public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
  return entityManager;
 }

 public void updateTask(Task task) {
  entityManager.merge(task);
 }

}


@Repository
@Transactional
public class TasksFirstDao extends TasksDaoAbstract {

 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 @Override
 public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
  return entityManager;
 }

 public void updateTask(Task task) { entityManager.merge(task); }

}



public abstract class TasksDaoAbstract { 

 @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.NEVER)
 public List<Task> getAll() {
  return getEntityManager().createQuery("FROM Task", 
  Task.class).getResultList();
  }


  public abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

 }
```

In general this code is working. But if I am trying to put updateTask method in the abstract class (with @Transactional) it look like the code is working (no error) but the DB is not updating.

I can not understand why the query is not working from the abstract class, the query that only getting data from the db is working from the abstract class.

Comment: show the query that gets the data from abstract class

Comment: so what do you think, which entity manager is it going to use if you move it to the abstract class???

Comment: if i will put the method in the abstract class it will look like this: @Transactional public void updateTask(Task task) { getEntityManager().merge(task); }

Comment: It should work that way and it should persist to the DB that is linked to the instance you're callling it from